# Adding external jQuery plugin to the existing HTML page

Tags: jquery

I am new to web design. I have created a gallery page by using HTML5 CSS3 and JavaScript. For my preference I have used internal CSS and JavaScript. Now I want to add a jQuery lightbox plugin which I have got extracted. The jQuery plugin has a 4 JS files with it. Is it okay if I just add the links of those JS files to my HTML or do I have to change the related elements in my HTML, CSS and JavaScript in order to work them together?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: it all depends on the plugin. In almost all cases yes, you must write the code (HTML and JS) according to the plugin documentation to make it work.

Comment: read their documentation http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Just add it after jQuery in your html file and then use it in your JS file or between script tags

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="C:\Users\haines\Desktop\Music\resource\jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(
        $("html").niceScroll();
      );
    </script>
```